# Ivevihvw Zokszyvg Kfaaov

Tags: mathematics, cipher

Vevib ovggvi szh yvvm ivkozxvw drgs gsv xliivhklmwrmt ovggvi rm gsv ivevihvw zokszyvg.

Rh gsv mfnyvi lu ovggvih rm gsv zylev hvmgvmxv kirnv li xlnklhrgv?

Comment: Is this an original puzzle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just

> a sentence in the Atbash cipher - the cipher where A is swapped with Z, B with Y, and so on.
>
>  The title is `Reversed Alphabet Puzzle`.
>
>  The text of the question is:
>  `Every letter has been replaced with the corresponding letter in the reversed alphabet.`
>  `Is the number of letters in the above sentence prime or composite?`
>
>  If I've counted correctly, there are 73 letters in that sentence, which is a prime number.